# How do I change an image with a button click?

Tags: javascript, button, events, addeventlistener

I am trying to change the image src with a click of a div, not a button element. But it does not work.

Here is my html:

```
 <figure class = "imgContainer">
<img class = "image" id = "image" src = " " alt = "activeimage">
```

```
 <div class = "buttonsContainer" id = "btctn1">
      <div class = "button" id = "btn1"></div>
      <div class = "button" id = "btn2"></div>
      <div class = "button" id = "btn3"></div>
      <div class = "button" id = "btn4"></div>
    </div>
```

javascript:

```
function setSrc() {
  let mysrc = "assets/chad.jpg";
  const img = document.getElementById("image");

  if(img != mysrc){
    img.src = msrc;
  }

 const btn1=document.getElementById("btn1");
  btn1.addEventListener("click", setSrc);
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can use the `onclick` event on the div tag to call a javascript function. In the function, create an array of image urls and choose a url based on the index sent by the div tag.

Try this code:

```
<script>
function setSrc(i) {
  let mysrc = 
  [ "D:\\pics\\cubered.png",
    "D:\\pics\\cubegreen.png",
    "D:\\pics\\cubeblue.png",
    "D:\\pics\\cubeyellow.png"]
  document.getElementById("image").src = mysrc[i];
}

//const btn1=document.getElementById("btn1");
//btn1.addEventListener("click", setSrc);
</script>

<figure class = "imgContainer">
<img class = "image" id = "image" src = " " alt = "activeimage">
 <div class = "buttonsContainer" id = "btctn1">
      <div class = "button" id = "btn1" onclick=setSrc(0)>BTN 1</div>
      <div class = "button" id = "btn2" onclick=setSrc(1)>BTN 2</div>
      <div class = "button" id = "btn3" onclick=setSrc(2)>BTN 3</div>
      <div class = "button" id = "btn4" onclick=setSrc(3)>BTN 4</div>
    </div>
    
<script>setSrc(0);</script>
```